# How to prevent GRUB wipe effect

Tags: grub2, nvidia

I recently switched graphics cards from a Radeon 5850 HD to a EVGA GeForce GTX 950. With the Radeon card, the GRUB screen would just appear, but with the EVGA card, the screen takes a few seconds to turn from black to purple with a upward wiping effect. Then the GRUB menu takes a few seconds to appear with the same wiping effect. Then once GRUB times out, the screen clears with the wiping effect. Why does this happen, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Hmmm... sounds like there is a conflict between GRUB and the GPU's VESA mode...